# Upgrade Magento 2 via composer not working

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, json

I try to upgrade **Magento 2.1.6** to **Magento 2.1.9**.

To do this I ran this command:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.9 --no-update
```

after this I ran : `composer update` and I received this error:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

> - The requested package magento/product-community-edition 2.1.9 exists as magento/product-community-edition[2.1.6] but these are rejected by
>     your constraint

My `composer.json` look like this:

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.1.9",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.9",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib": "^3.0",
        "mailchimp/mc-magento2": "^1.0",
        "dividebv/phpdivideiq": "^0.5.0",
        "beberlei/assert": "^2.4"
    },
.........................................
```

Even I remove the rest of the extensions like this, is still not working

```
   "require": {
            "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.6",
            "composer/composer": "@alpha"

        },
```

How I can avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your `composer.json` edit your version number on line `5` and `11` to 2.1.9, Then just run `composer update`

Comment: after i run composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.9 --no-update my composer.json is 2.1.9, but i have the same issue

Comment: have you setup a repository in your composer.json to get the new version from?

Comment: no. but i am not sure what do you mean

Comment: you should surely just update the packages you're interested in rather than every package installed on your system? eg `composer update foo/bar baz/qux`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the rest of the extensions like

```
"magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.6",
```

is not enough, you should remove it from composer lock as well, or do like below,

```
composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.1.9 --no-update
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try to remove the Magento through composer and then update the version. Also, check the PHP and MySQL versions before proceeding.

```
composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.1.9 --no-update
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

For Magento 2.1.x system requirements, please follow these links.
https://meetanshi.com/blog/magento-2-system-requirements/